# Perforce: judge if codeline A is branched from codeline B

Tags: branch, perforce

The question is straight forward: given two codelines, A and B, respectively, how can Perforce tell if A is branched or not from B, and vice versa?

I believe that this information should be keep tracked but not explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `p4 filelog` on any file in the tree to see also the history of the file (including where it was branched from).
For indirect ancestors you can call the "Revision History" graph (in the P4V Gui).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, we cannot grab any file to do the 'filelog', because 1)that after branching, there are some new files added to the child branch and we cannot track that info; 2) two branching operation performed to the same directory, then we cannot know from filelog from those files branched from another codeline, say C

Comment: Your situation is not clear to me. Maybe this is of help for you.
1) use "p4 interchanges -f //depot/sourcetree/... //depot/targettree/..." to find out about changes/files that have not yet been integrated/branched.
2) p4 filelog definitely tells you from and whereto a file was branched/integrated.
There's all information you might need in that output.